# invalidateが.realmに与える影響と、writeToCopyURLが.realmに与える影響

Tags: realm

invalidateが.realmに与える影響と、writeToCopyURLが.realmに与える影響をご教授いただけ‌​ないでしょうか？

どちらの関数も.realmファイ‌​ルのサイズを小さくできておりますが、Realmが何を‌​してファイルを小さくしているのか知りたい‌​のです。
realmに保存しているデータ‌​は個人情‌​報など非常に大事な情報も含まれます。
各関数が.realmに与える影響や、具‌​体的に何をしているのか教えてください。

Answer (score 1):

まず勘違いされていますが、`invalidate()`はファイルの増加を間接的に抑制する効果がありますが、ファイルを小さくするわけでは **ありません** 。

RealmはMVCC（Multi version concurrent control）という仕組みでトランザクションを管理しています。
これは簡単にいうとトランザクションごとにその時点のスナップショットを持ち、別のトランザクション中に読み込みがあった場合は古いデータのスナップショットを返すことでデータの一貫性を保ちつつ、読み込みは書き込みと競合することがないという利点を持っています。そのため、間接的にファイルサイズの増加を抑えられる可能性があります。

ただし、トランザクションを長い間開いていた場合、スナップショットのデータが多量に作成されることがあります。`invalidate()`はRealmに現在生きているオブジェクト（＝スナップショット）にもうこれ以上アクセスすることはなく、破棄しても構わないということを、マニュアル操作で伝えるメソッドです。それにより、スナップショットが不要に作成されることを防ぐ効果が期待できます。

不要になったスナップショットの領域は後に再利用されますが、Realmはその領域を自動的に取り除くことはしません。そのためRealmのファイルサイズは基本的には増加するだけで減少することは **ありません** 。

しかし、それでは不便なので、将来の空き領域として保持されている不要なスナップショットのデータを取り除いて最適化する操作が用意されています。

Realmではその操作をコンパクションと呼んでいます。コンパクションのAPIは公開されてないので、直接呼ぶことはできません。その代わりに、`writeToCopyURL()`のメソッドを使うことで、コピー先のファイルはコンパクション済みのファイルになります。元のファイルが小さくなるわけではありません。かつ必ず小さくなるわけでもありません。あくまで、不要なスナップショット領域がある場合に、その部分が除去されるのでファイルサイズが小さくなります。

参考までに、半自動的にコンパクションを行うAPIとして`shouldCompactOnLaunch`という設定があります。これを使うと、Realmを最初に開く時に、内部でファイルのコピーを作成し、オリジナルと入れ替えるという操作をして、あたかも元のファイルがコンパクションされたかのように振舞うことができます。

Comment: 将来の空き領域として保持されている不要なスナップショットのデータを取り除いて最適化する操作が用意されています <- とありますが、スナップショットとは実際にRealmに保存されている情報を破棄しているという認識でしょうか、スナップショットとは何でしょうか、<- キャッシュ的なものなのでしょうか

Comment: RealmはMVCC(Multi-Version Concurrency Control)という仕組みでトランザクションを管理しています。トランザクションごとにバージョン履歴としてデータが積み重なっていくようなものです。 Gitを使ったことがあればそれと同じようなものだと考えても構いません。トランザクションの一貫性のため、トランザクション中のデータが他のスレッドから見えてはいけません。MVCCではトランザクション中に別のスレッドからアクセスがあった場合、１つ古いバージョンのデータを返します。それにより、読み込みを一切ブロックすることなくトランザクションの一貫性を保てます。ここで言っているスナップショットとはそれぞれの時点のバージョンのデータになります。

Comment: 余談ですが、Realmはモバイル環境におけるパフォーマンスのために、ゼロコピーと遅延ロードを徹底しています。必要になるまで（＝実際にプロパティにアクセスがあるまで）一切データをメモリに保持したりコピーしません。そのように作られています。なのでキャッシュとかそういう概念は一旦忘れてください。

Comment: キャッシュという概念ではなく、スナップショットという概念を用いて、書き込み、読み込みを行うのですね、そのスナップショットの為の領域に書き込まないようにするのが,invalidateで、writeToCopyURLで不要なスナップショットの領域を破棄するのでこのような効果が期待できるということでなのですね、

Comment: 厳密には書き込み、読み込みではなくてトランザクションの管理ですね。`invalidate`は書き込まないようにということではなくて、もう現在のオブジェクトは使わない（無効にしてもよい）ということを知らせるメソッドです。

Comment: 結果的に小さくなりますが、細かいことは良いのでしょうか

Comment: そうではなくてinvalidateとwriteCopyToURLでは、処理の内容や起こる結果が全然違うものということを説明しています。何のために気にしていらっしゃるのか分からないので、目的や、何か具体的な問題が起こってるなら、それを書いていただけると、それに即した回答ができると思います。

Comment: 結果が全然違うもの <- 私の見解では Invalidate は結果スナップショットを書き込まない、　writeToCopyToURLは　結領域確保されたスナップショットを最適化する。